# Node.js and recrusive reading from api

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently building some things with Node.js, and I've noticed something that I think could be optimized. However, I lack the experience to do so, and I would like to learn how to optimize it.

Here's the problem I'm facing:

I have a function that is called every 3 seconds using setTimeout. Within this interval function, there are three other functions that read data from Crypto Exchanges' APIs. The interval function should ideally print a new console.log every 3 seconds to confirm that everything is running smoothly without any blockages.

However, I've observed that the time intervals between console logs are often several seconds, sometimes even 10 or 30 seconds. I'm aware that this is caused by the functions called within the interval function, but I lack the experience to optimize it.

Now, let me explain what the functions called within the interval function do. These functions work recursively, for example, they retrieve all completed trades from an exchange account. Since the API only returns 100 trades at a time, I had to build the function recursively to fetch additional trades until the entire trade history is retrieved.

One solution would be to remove the recursive reading and instead read the next 100 trades every 3 seconds. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to optimize the code so that Node.js continues the recursive reading in the background without blocking the execution of the interval function. In other words, I would like to achieve the following: the interval function prints a new console log every 3 seconds, while the recursive reading continues in the background, without blocking the overall program execution.

I would like to learn how to do this as I still lack sufficient experience with Node.js. Do you have any good tips?

Here are some code exampels to understand my current building:

```
function IntervalFunction1()
{
  try
  {
console.log("=================================================================================================================================");
  console.log("============================================ IntervalFunction1 "+new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString()+" ===========================================================================");
  console.log("=================================================================================================================================");

  let a=0;
  OpenOrdersAndBalance(Kontos[a].account, Kontos[a].key, Kontos[a].secret);
  GetClosedTradesRecursive(Kontos[a].account, Kontos[a].key, Kontos[a].secret);
  GetOrders(Kontos[a].account, Kontos[a].key, Kontos[a].secret);
 
  setTimeout(IntervalFunction1, 3000);
 }
 catch (error)
 {
    console.error('IntervalFunction1, Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten:', error);
    setTimeout(IntervalFunction1, 3000);
 }
}//IntervalFunction1
IntervalFunction1();


async function GetOrders(account, key, secret, nextPageCursor = '')
{ 
  const Client = new FuturesClient({
     apiKey: key,
     apiSecret: secret,
  });

  try {
      const getOrders = await Client.getProductTypeOrderHistory("usdt", 0, Date.now(), '100', nextPageCursor);
      for(let a=0; a<Object.size(getOrders.data.orderList); a++)
      {
         //console.log("getOrders result: ", getOrders.data.orderList[a]);
      }
      //wenn es mehr daten gibt wird hier ein nextpagecursor gelesen und die funktion wird recrusive erneut aufgerufen
      let nextPage = ""; if(getOrders.data.endId !== undefined)nextPage=getOrders.data.endId; if(getOrders.data.nextFlag == false)nextPage="";

      if(nextPage !== "")
      {
          setTimeout(async () => {
            await GetOrders(account, key, secret, nextPage);
          }, 900);
      }
      else
      {
         console.log("========= get orders gespeichert ==================");
      }
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error('request failed: ', e);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's been a bit of a while since I've done Node.js so I'm not completely sure but try moving the `setTimeout(IntervalFunction1, 3000);` call above the `GetOrders(Kontos[a].account, Kontos[a].key, Kontos[a].secret);` and see if that fixes anything.